# How to assign value of one variable to another in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I tried with below two ways. Both are working fine, I want to know which one is good in terms of performance as i have to use it in procedure multiple times.

1. `var1 := var2;`
2. `SELECT var2 INTO var1 FROM dual;`

Comment: Option 1. is definitely the better choice

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is to be preferred as it will perform at least as well as option 2 and possibly better, and it is succinct and makes sense.

Using option 2 is verbose and not sensible.  At best the PL/SQL optimizer may make it perform as well as option 1, but it cannot be better.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if var2 value is greater than 30 characters, it will give identifier too long error. so prefer option 1.